# IMAP SEARCH CHARSET with ISO-8859-1

Tags: character-encoding, imap, iso-8859-1, thunderbird

I can't understand what encoding approach uses **Tunderbird** while searching on IMAP server with command **IMAP SEARCH CHARSET**

I've tried to search Russian word "привет" and this was mapped to "?@825B", i.e.

```
A001 SEARCH CHARSET ISO-8859-1 BODY "?@825B"
```

How that happen? I'm sure this is correct as I've used sniffer for catch this and the **Dovecot** server correctly found the mail with "привет" word. The ISO-8859-1 encoding hasn't Russian glyphs at all! So how it was converted?

For example, **"привет"** (written as Unicode characters) gives **"??????"** for **ISO-8859-1** encoding on my machine or here http://www.motobit.com/util/charset-codepage-conversion.asp

Comment: The string you have doesn't look at all like UTF-8. In fact, it looks like some legacy 8-bit Cyrillic encoding (KOI-8? CP1251?) stripped of its eighth bit. We can only speculate about where this happens. A good start would be a hex dump of the actual bytes.

Comment: Why do you think that symbols from "привет" word are not existed at UTF-8? Please see HEX dump for it at UTF-8: d0 bf d1 80 d0 b8 d0 b2 d0 b5 d1 82

Comment: Yes, that's what it should be, but there is no obvious mapping from that to "?@825B" and usually you would also get as many question marks as bytes. So I'm guessing what is being passed in is not really UTF-8.

Comment: And what is this if not UTF-8? I have default system charset as UTF-8 and when I type on my keyboard the word "привет" to Thunderbird's dialog window for search I expect that "привет" is written in UTF-8 encoding. Don't?

Comment: What comes out the other end is wrong; there's no way to deduce from this information where exactly it's going wrong. It may well be a bug in Thunderbird.

Answer (score 0):

The way that Thunderbird is getting this value is by downcasting a (16-bit?) unicode character to a byte.

For example, in C# (which uses UTF-16 internally for its char and string types), this would get the result you are seeing:

```
const string text = "привет";

var buffer = new char[text.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    buffer[i] = (char) ((byte) text[i]);

var result = new string (buffer);
```

How Thunderbird handles surrogate pairs is anyone's guess based on what is known from the question. It might treat the surrogate pair as 2 separate characters (like my above code would) or it might combine them into a 32-bit unicode character and downcast that to a byte.